# Retrieve JSON field name from selector in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have created a conditional selector using the second approach shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/

In my case I have a one to one relationship between the second key (San Francisco) and the third value (SOMA,Burbank,...) as shown below:

```
function StaticCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = {
        'usa': {
            'San Francisco': 'SOMA',
            'Los Angeles': 'Burbank'
        },
        'canada': {
            'People dont live here':'igloo'
        }
    };
}

    <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="cities" ng-options="country for (country, cities) in countries">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="suburbs" ng-options="city for (city, suburbs) in cities"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
    </div>
```

If I select usa in the first dropdown and San Francisco in the second, I can get the following values:

```
    {{suburbs}}
```

Which gives me `SOMA`

Or

```
    {{cities}}
```

Which gives me

```
    {       'San Francisco': 'SOMA',
            'Los Angeles': 'Burbank'     }
```

I would like to retrieve the field name selected on the second dropdown `San Francisco` to call a function.

Is there a way to do so without doing changes in the json structure?

Comment: To be honest, I don't get the question :-S

Comment: Sorry, I will try to edit and improve it a bit. 
The issue is that I have two conditional dropdowns and I want to retrieve the value selected in the second dropdown. 
I can get either the whole element({{cities}} :  {
            'San Francisco': 'SOMA',
            'Los Angeles': 'Burbank'
        } 
or the value of the selected element({{suburbs}}): 'SOMA'
I want to get the element's key 'San Francisco'

Comment: can you post your code to jsffidle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I strongly suggest you keep working with your **second approach**, the one that relies on a **static dataset**.

---

Second, you need to only retrieve the **country**(/city/suburb)**'s name** as the `ngModel` for each of your `select` elements.
Then, you populate the next `select`'s value by **browsing your dataset** using the currently selected *path* (i.e.: country > city > suburb).

---

For example, here's what your **country** `select` element should look like:

```
<select id="city" ng-disabled="!country" ng-model="city" ng-options="city as city for (city, suburbs) in countries[country]">
```

The `$scope.city` simply holds the **name** of the selected city, and the corresponding suburbs are stored and available in: `{{countries[country][city]}}`.

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63z8d63b/) for illustration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution was extremely helpful, I am making my first steps with Angular and I was struggling with this.